# Cannot make a thumbnail of the uploaded image with php

Tags: php, image

I need to make a thumbnail of an image after successfully uploaded the image file. I wrote this function but it seems doesn't work. Hope anyone could help. Thanks

```
function make_thumb( $src, $thumbDest, $thumbWidth ){
    $sourceImage  = imagecreatefromjpeg( $src );
    $theWidth     = imagesx( $sourceImage );
    $theHeight    = imagesy( $sourceImage );

    $thumbHeight = floor( $theHeight * ( $thumbWidth / $theWidth ) );
    $tempImage   = imagecreatetruecolor( $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight );
    imagecopyresized( $tempImage, $sourceImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight, $theWidth, $theHeight );

    imagejpeg( $tempImage, $thumbDest );
    imagedestroy( $tempImage );
    imagedestroy( $sourceImage );
}
```

Comment: It doesn't save the supposedly created thumbnail image into the destination folder given and nothing shows up.

Comment: Did you enabled error_reporting directive? Also check your error log.

Comment: Yes, thanks. it works now :). Actually the error caused by the destination folder and the filename. I didn't pass the filename to be saved it, i only passed the destination.

Comment: So you should have had an error :s

Comment: Yes, it had shown the error but the error message i couldn't see because it was hidden by html tag. Anyway, it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Linux, check the /var/log/httpd/error_log or /var/log/apache2/error_log to see the reason why it failed (if you have error reporting turned off.)

Also, it may due to a file permission issue. Make sure that the $thumbDest destination folder/directory is writable by the user that Apache or the web server is running as.